# Problema con variable en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

soy nuevo en codeigniter y no puedo representar una variable en la vista cada vez que hago un echo en la vista me da el mensaje "array to string conversion" pero se supone que la consulta en el modelo solo devuelve un número que representa la cantidad COUNT. Para mi no debiera ser un array creo?adjunto código. Desde ya muchas gracias

// El modelo que hace la consulta utiliza una variable de sesion para comparar 's_id_area' desde otra funcion antes de esta

```
public function principal() {
    $id_area = $this->session->userdata('s_id_area');
    $this->db->select('COUNT(id_categoria)');
    $this->db->from('categorias');
    $this->db->where('id_area', $id_area);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

//el controlador carga el modelo y obtiene la variable y la carga en la vista vprincipal

```
<?php
```

/**
 *
 */
class Cprincipal extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('mlogin');

}

public function index() {
    $data['resultado'] = $this->mlogin->principal();
    $this->load->view('layout/header');
    $this->load->view('layout/menu');
    $this->load->view('persona/vprincipal', $data);
    $this->load->view('layout/footer');

}
```

}

// Finalmente la vista

```
<div class="info">
            <h4>Categorías</h4>
            <p><b><?php echo $resultado ?></b></p>
          </div>
        </div>`introducir el código aquí`
```

// he colocado var_dump($resultado)  y me devuelve **"array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["COUNT(id_categoria)"]=> string(1) "7" } }"** 7 es el valor que debería devolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como has apreciado, estás obteniendo un `array`. El método `result()` de **Codeigniter** te devuelve un `array` de objetos.

Ya que la consulta aparentemente te devuelve una fila, podrías usar el método `row()` en vez de `result()`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

$row = $query->row();

if (isset($row))
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

Dado que lo que pareces necesitar es el número de resultados que arroja la consulta, en **Codeigniter** tenemos una función específica que nos devuelve eso, `num_rows()`:

```
public function principal() {
    $id_area = $this->session->userdata('s_id_area');
    $this->db->where('id_area', $id_area);
    $resultado = $this->db->get('categorias')->num_rows();

    return $resultado;

}
```

**Referencia:** [Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Perdón, debiera ser $query = $this->db->get();

  $row = $query->row();

  if (isset($row)) {
   echo $row->id_area;

  }

Comment: Edité mi respuesta para darte una función simplificada de lo que tienes y que te devolvería directamente el `count` de la consulta.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias ....se que es una pregunta tonta, pero estoy aprendiendo y hacer consultas con codeigniter es diferente a hacerlo sin framework. Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¡Un placer! En cuanto le pilles el punto verás que te agiliza un montón el tema del acceso a DB.